# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ completely reducible

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\Pi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation (complex and finite-dim if necessary) of the infinite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$. Then is there an inner product such that $\Pi$ is unitary? If not, is $\Pi$ completely reducible?

I know this is true for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and it seems that it would be true for $\mathbb{Z}$ if we take $n\rightarrow \infty$. However, I'm not sure with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $V = \mathbb{C}^n$ by $n.v = \lambda^n v$ for some fixed $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda| \not = 1$. Then any inner product on $V$ has $\langle{n.v, n.v\rangle} = |\lambda|^{2n} \langle{v, v\rangle}$, so the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not unitary for it.

For the second part, the representation $\mathbb{Z} \to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ sending the  generator to $g = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is not irreducible (as it fixes $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$) and also not the direct sum of irreps (as that would diagonalize $g$).